# SCons env.Install("path_to_folder") does not show folder files in dependency tree

Tags: installation, scons

In SCons when a folder is installed the dependency tree is not aware of the contents of the folder. This means that implicit relationships cannot be created.

```
env.Install("out/bin","path/to/folder")
env.Install("out/archive", Glob("out/bin/folder/library.lib"))
```

In this sample code the Glob returns [] because SCons is unaware the folder contains a file called library.lib.

The only workaround I've found for this is to walk the directory and install each individual file.

Does the SCons Install not have an option to do this for you?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this as well.  I have not found any other solution than to walk the directories as you describe.  Though the contents of the folder are copied, to SCons there is just one target, and just one source, unless you specify each one individually.

```
import os
def recursive_install(target, source, env):
    source_dirname = os.path.dirname(source)
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source):
        for filename in filenames:
            env.Install(os.path.join(
                target, os.path.relpath(root, os.path.dirname(source))),
                os.path.join(root, filename))

env = Environment()
recursive_install("out/bin", "path/to/folder", env)
env.Install("out/archive", "out/bin/folder/library.lib")
```

Which when run produces...

```
>> scons --version
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    script: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine path: ['/usr/lib/scons/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2014 The SCons Foundation

>> tree
.
├── path
│   └── to
│       └── folder
│           └── library.lib
└── SConstruct

3 directories, 2 files

>> scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
Install file: "path/to/folder/library.lib" as "out/bin/folder/library.lib"
Install file: "out/bin/folder/library.lib" as "out/archive/library.lib"
scons: done building targets.

>> tree
.
├── out
│   ├── archive
│   │   └── library.lib
│   └── bin
│       └── folder
│           └── library.lib
├── path
│   └── to
│       └── folder
│           └── library.lib
└── SConstruct

7 directories, 4 files
```

Comment: The issue with individual Installs is that it's possible for only the a file to get copied rather than the entire folder. To fix this I created a builder + pseudo-builder. Together they listed all the targets that are created and the implementation used shutils.copytree(..). Hence if any one of the files in the folder was needed it copied the entire directory.

Comment: @ShaneGannon, it sounds like what you did should work, but I do not see how the `recursive_install` function above would not accomplish the same thing.  If you individually installed just one file in the directory yes, but not if you call `recursive_install` with the target and source directories.

Comment: Imagine I had a folder "main" with 2 libraries "one.lib" & "two.lib" which I want to copy to "out". In my build I have a dependency upon "out/main/one.lib". SCons recognizes the Install builder (from recursive_install) will create this file. Hence it executes it on the 2nd pass. But nothing depends upon "out/main/two.lib". Hence it's install builder does not run on the 2nd pass. i.e. recursive_install by itself only caused a sub-set of the folder to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

SCons doesn't have an option for recursively installing all files under a top-folder, because that's considered to be a rare case (note, how SCons prefers in-source-tree builds, such that you'd have to exclude a lot of files from the Install call otherwise). If you are creating the "files to install" within the same build, the preferred method would be to use the emitted list of targets from your Builder, and put it as second argument to the Install method:

```
mylibs = env.AnyBuilder('library', sources)
env.Install("out/bin", mylibs)
```

Then you don't have to manually list all the target files again with a recursive os.walk as in Kenneth's answer.

Comment: The folder I want to copy already exists. It is not created by a builder. In this suggestion only the files used by the build will get installed. i.e. Because SCons threats each node in mylibs as an individual install. I want to install all files even if only one is used by the build.